# How to Build an RPM from Source in One Line without Spec Files etc?

Tags: redhat, fedora, centos7, rpm, rhel

I've been reading about building RPMs, and the process is quite complex. Is there any program/software that works like this:

1. Download tar.gz file. Extract to directory
2. cd into directory
3. Run
4. RPM file is output into the directory

Does any such program exist? It seems as if it *should*. After all, when I run make, make install etc, I don't need to specify spec files, provide locations for where the software has to be installed. So why should I have to do all that for creating RPMs?

I've tried using checkinstall, but I keep getting errors like "Directory not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/hello-2.10-1.x86_64/usr"

So is there an easier way?

Comment: I don't know if what you're asking for exists, but I don't think you're comparison with make is valid. When you run make, you need a Makefile to tell make the definition of the various targets. 

How would the tool you have in mind know:

1. How to build the project
2. What the output artifact(s) are 
3. Where these artifacts should be deployed on the target filesystem
4. What the file permissions should be etc.

Comment: Hmm. If I can currently use "make" and "make install" without problems, can the tool I have in mind simply its information from the same places that "make" and "make install" get their info?

The tool "checkinstall" is supposed to do something like this, but I can't get it to work for RPMs. A workaround I have is to create "deb" files instead and use alien to convert deb -> rpm. But it's imperfect of course...

I just type "checkinstall" and the rpm/deb is created (bugged for rpms). No need for spec files.

Comment: Fair enough...I see what you mean. The way the question is phrased, it wasn't clear (to me anyway) that you want to create the rpm from the info in your Makefile. That might be doable but it will probably result in a really complicated Makefile. We maintain a lot of rpm spec files in my project, and honestly they don't contain much redundant info. 

In any case, this still isn't really creating an rpm "from source". You still need the Makefile to provide all the info an rpm needs regarding dependencies etc. And if you need pre/post install scripts, it'll get complicated quickly.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no easier way.

Sometimes upstream provide 'make rpm' target. Sometime checkinstall works. But often you have to create the spec file manually.

BTW that error from checkinstall reveals two things:

- you are running that command as root. That is very very unwise.
- you should create few build directories. Run command `rpmdev-setuptree` it will create them for you.

Comment: Thanks for that! I already have those directories set up and when I run checkinstall as another user, I just get a similar error...

Comment: The only thing that works for me so far is to use checkinstall to create a .deb file, then use alien to convert .deb -> .rpm .If checkinstall doesn't need a SPEC file to create rpms, then why do we need one?

Comment: Checkinstall just monitor 'make install' and put all installed files in %files section. Leaving all other section to their defaults. Which can be fine for super easy packages. But you usually need to specify dependencies, post install scripts (to restart daemons), create user before installing packages, mark some files as configs.... This can be hardly done automatically for general software.